# Live streaming with silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, streaming, video-streaming

Greeting,
Is there a live streaming server for silverlight 4 from Microsoft like Flash Media Server from Adobe that support live streaming for Flash???

I know that there are many open source live streaming server that support silverlight 4 but I did not find some one good as Flash Media Server which support Flash!!!

please tell me if Microsoft has a media server for live streaming or if there is a good open source server for that.

I'm working in building web conference system using  silverlight 4 but I have problem with server that all the open source servers I used are really slow.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft supply a range of services for media including live streaming.

See [Windows Media Services](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/forpros/serve/prodinfo2008.aspx).

Also take a look at [Live Smooth Streaming for iis 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/620/live-smooth-streaming-for-iis-7---getting-started/)